# how to save Editable s value in afterTextChanged?

Tags: android, textchanged

I am going to save the value in one textview after the length of input string is fulfilled. but saved value is empty if the value of textview is used. If Editable **s** value in afterTextChanged is used, it causes crash.

Some codes as following:
`number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
final String numberStr = number.getText().toString();`

if following afterTextChanged is used, empty value is saved even I already input sth.

```
  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 11) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, numberStr , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveSettingNote(MainActivity.this, "number_save", "number", numberStr);
                number.setText(getSettingNote(MainActivity.this,"number_save", "number"));
            } 
        }
```

if following code is used, it will cause crash:

```
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (s.length() == 11) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveSettingNote(MainActivity.this, "number_save", "number", s.toString());
                number.setText(getSettingNote(MainActivity.this,"number_save", "number"));
            } 
        }
```

Saving and getting are based on SharedPreferences, which works well in other situation.

Actually, what I want to implement is saving String after the criteria is fulfilled for input string.

Please help to identify what is wrong in above code or suggest a new to get that function. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you paste your crash log ? Did you check `if (s != null){}` ?

Comment: I run this in a real phone. where does the crash log I could find? actually, I input the string and the length of the input is already judged. So s should not be null.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio to load into phone to test, check `Logcat`. When program crash, there will be error message there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and suggestions. I use one SAVE button to implement the function, which is simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because your listener is looping indefinitely with the same value passed in over and over.

The ugly truth is that you've to unbind your listener, set the value and then bind it again:

```
@Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.length() == 11) {
                // unbind your listener
                editText.addTextChangedListener(null);

                // do your stuff
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveSettingNote(MainActivity.this, "number_save", "number", s.toString()); 
                number.setText(getSettingNote(MainActivity.this,"number_save", "number"));

                // bind your listener again
                editText.addTextChangedListener(MainActivity.this);
            } 
        }
```

Using [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) you can achieve this in a more elegant way:

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
            .map { it.toString() }
            .filter({ it.length == 11 })
            .distinctUntilChanged() // <-- the important part
            .subscribe(
                { s -> /* do your stuff here */}
            )
```

Comment: When I try the ugly way, the editText is not recognized by android studio :( Anyway maybe the original idea is ugly too. I use one SAVE button to simple it. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Q.QQ replace `editText` with the name of your `EditText` variable, which is `number `

Answer (score 0):

you set text in editext afterTextChanged(Editable s) which calls text change listener again and again and cause the application to crash. call `number.setText(getSettingNote(MainActivity.this,"number_save", "number"));` outside the text change listener.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that by declaring `numberStr` as you did, you expect to change its value each time the edit text change its content. However, this is not the case; it will be initialised with an empty string `""` (unless you don't have any other string in the edit text at that moment) and then it will NEVER change its value, thus resulting in the empty value that you save. As solution I would suggest to make `numberStr` non final and update its value (like you already did) each time before showing the `Toast`.